# Generating character base on 4-bit input

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am extremely new to PIC programming and need some help. I am using MPLAB v3.55 with xc8 compiler. Basically, I want a code to generate a character based on the truth table below. I am using a pic18f4520 microcontroller and the A,B,C,D are connected to PORT A bits 0 to 3. Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]
[image]

Comment: The table has 16 unique values in binary, in the range `0..15`. Make a 16-element array like `int lookup[16] = { 1, 2, 3, 0xF, 4 ... };` etc. Or make a character array if you prefer `char lookup[16] = "123F456E789DA0BC";` but you might have to convert these back to a digit value, depending on the use case. Then if you read the 4-bit pattern `patt` the conversion is `lookup[patt]`.The lines A,B,C & D are connected to port bits 0..3 so that makes it staightforward: `int patt = *porta & 15;` (say, depending on how you read a port).

Comment: Made a 16 element array with a "key" char variable. So if portc=lookup[1] then key is 1. Is there a shorter way of doing it rather than having 16 if statements?

Comment: I don't understand why you need 16 `if` statements. It's just an array, indexed by the keyboard data, and the array contains what it says on the keytops.

Comment: If I want to lets say send the appropriate key data somewhere else, don't I need if statements?

Comment: No. The key pressed comes directly from (something like) `int key = lookup [PORTA & 15]`; It's unclear whether you are using port A or port C. You'll need the `if` to check if RD0 is telling you the data will be valid.

Comment: wait but lets say the key pressed is "A". Shouldn't the code be if(portc=lookup[13]) key="A" no? Do not get this line: int key = lookup [PORTA & 15]

Comment: There are 16 possible values from 4 ports bits (and 16 keys). So key **A** is pressed, and the binary value `1100` appears on the port. You use that value (12) to index the array, where in the `char` version `lookup[12]` has the value `'A'` (or the `int` version `lookup[12]` has the value `10`). This is basic C, nothing to do with PIC or device programming.

Comment: What if I were to feed this data onto an LCD module for display? Is the if version applicable then?

Comment: I dont understand the PORTA & 15 line

Comment: You read 8 bits from a port. You aren't interested in bits 4-7 so they are masked off with `PORTA & 15`. The `15` being binary `00001111`. Then the 8 bits you read are in the range 0-15 and can be used to index the 16-element array.

Comment: What if I were to use the char version? 'char keypressed[16]= { ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ‘F’, ‘4’, ‘5’, ‘6’, ‘E’, ‘7’,  ‘8’, ‘9’, ‘D’, ‘A’, ‘0’, ‘B’, ‘C’}'

Comment: That's exactly the same, except it gives a different data type.

Comment: I am still so lost sorry, im a newbie. Lets say we use the char version. And for example key F is pressed, how does the code work?

Comment: I described that for the **A** key in a [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963460/generating-character-base-on-4-bit-input?noredirect=1#comment123675494_69963460).

Comment: Ok if A is pressed and the port has a value of 1100, and we use the code char key = lookup[portA & 15]? How does that make key=A?

Comment: I really do need to. But how does PORT A & 15 = 12?

Comment: The `12` come from your truth table. In the row where the right-hand **Key** column has **A** the data value at the port is binary `1100` which is decimal `12`. If you mask that with `15` (to remove the upper bits) it remains unchanged. The upper bits are not in the table, they are unknown, but not wanted, so we mask them off - if the port data was `10101100` then ANDing with `00001111` removes the upper 4 bits and preserves the lower 4 bits.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense, I approached this totally wrong. Can you tell me why it is wrong to do it like if PORTC = something then key = something

Comment: *You* already told *me* why it is wrong. Because you need 16 `if` statements, instead of one array read.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. By any chance, do you know what the OE(Output enabled) pin does?

Comment: The [data sheet](http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/document/d74c922.pdf) says *The output latches feed 3-STATE, which is enabled when the Output Enable (OE) input is taken lo.* Three-state means a pin can be high, low, or not driven.

Comment: Ok so since it's grounded means it's activated? I understand it controls the outputs between those 3 states but what does that do?

Comment: **OE** = "Output Enable".

Comment: What if I wanted to read the port c data whenever DA is HIGH? if(PORTD.bitsRD0==1) char data = PORTC; Is that right? Or what data type should 'data' be